# App in IBM bluemix is not working

Tags: ibm-cloud

My App in `ibm bluemix` is not working. It seems as though the jsp files are not processing correctly.

I'm getting this error message:

> javax.servlet.ServletExecption:SRVE0207E:Uncaught intialization
>   exception created by servlet. Erro Code:500

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you figure out what might be going wrong, an error message is hard to debug with no code.

Comment: Please post logs using `cf logs --recent` and your code so we can see what's going on. Thanks

Comment: Without the stack trace it is difficult to help.